# Wakeup Hotword for my Android Application

Tags: android, google-assist-api

I have an app and I want it to open using wakeword like "Hi Max" . For now I am using Pocketsphinx library to achieve that, but it is kind of continuous listening and putting a strain on battery. 
Google Assistant is doing it very efficiently [I dont have much idea but may be due to dedicated audio coprocessor], Is there any way where I can make use of that coprocessor or even google assistant itself for launching my application using the word.
[I don't want to do this - "Ok Google" -> "Hi Max" - I want to completely bypass "Ok Google"

I cannot find a way to do this, please suggest what to do. I am relatively new to android.